# How to specify the class selector in web scraping using nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, jsdom

Am trying to implement scraping using nodejs. Am sending request to a particular url and when i get the response, using the response am storing each products in a page into an array. For each product am trying to display the product details like product name, price and discount etc. Am doing this by the following code.

```
var $products = $body.find('.fashion-item');
$products.each(function (i, item) {
    var $name = ($(item).find('.info .title').text(),
        $price=$(item).find('span.price.regular').text().substr(6),
        $discount=$(item).find('span.price.percentoff').text().slice(0,2);
    self.items[i] = {
        title: $name,
        price: $price,
        discount: $discount,
    };
});
console.log(self.items);
```

It is working fine. If the class name is like 'fashion-item' or 'fashion-item-first' all this works fine. But if the class name contains the space in between the word, am not getting any products stored in array ($products) i.e. array length of $products is zero. My question is how to do the same thing if class name like this 'fashion-item first'. I tried very much, but i didn't get any idea. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class names cannot have spaces. In your example, `'fashion-item first'`, are two classes assigned to an element, which can be selected by either `.fashion-item` or `.first` selectors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want item who have both info and title classe select them with this :

```
$(item).find('.info.title')
```

If you want item one of these classes, use this

```
$(item).find('.info,.title)
```